# does not contain a definition for if contains by documentation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget

I installed System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt via Nuget.

```
Update-Package –reinstall System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
```

I need to use the class [TokenValidationParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.tokenvalidationparameters(v=vs.114).aspx).  When I do I get this error:

```
'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters' does not contain a definition
    for 'AudienceUriMode'
'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters' does not contain a definition
    for 'SigningToken'
```

but according to the documentation there, I tried to reinstall. I have System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt version 4.0.

I also have another error. I can't use [JwtSecurityToken Constructor (String, String, IEnumerable, Lifetime, SigningCredentials)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn451037(v=vs.114).aspx). Any Idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Answered by leastprivilege

specify a scope in your OAuth request

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/issues/600

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not my problem